# What is the cause for hydration error in my next.js project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

So I have a ThreadCard.tsx component and LikeButton.tsx component is inside that ThreadCard.tsx, LikeButton.tsx liked state will be different for each logged in user (I already finished this logic and fully implemented thread liking functionality in my app), but I get this hydration error bla bla...,

I knew that it is happen when HTML prepared by SSR is different from the client side HTML, but I cannot figure out where the problem arise from, maybe someone can help me spot the problem? thank you, oh, the ThreadCard.tsx is inside a page.tsx

`page.tsx` :

```
import ThreadCard from "@/components/cards/ThreadCard";
import Pagination from "@/components/shared/Pagination";
import { fetchPosts } from "@/lib/actions/thread.actions";
import { fetchUser } from "@/lib/actions/user.actions";
import { currentUser } from "@clerk/nextjs";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

async function Home({
  searchParams,
}: {
  searchParams: { [key: string]: string | undefined };
}) {
  const user = await currentUser();
  if (!user) return null;

  const userInfo = await fetchUser(user.id);
  if (!userInfo?.onboarded) redirect("/onboarding");

  const result = await fetchPosts(
    searchParams.page ? +searchParams.page : 1,
    30
  );

  return (
    <>
      <h1 className="head-text text-left">Home</h1>
      <section className="mt-9 flex flex-col gap-10 custom-scrollbar">
        {result.posts.length === 0 ? (
          <p className="no-result">No threads found</p>
        ) : (
          <>
            {result.posts.map(async (post, index) => {
              return (
                <ThreadCard
                  key={post._id}
                  id={post._id}
                  loggedInUser={user?.id || ""}
                  currentUserId={userInfo._id || ""}
                  parentId={post.parentId}
                  content={post.text}
                  author={post.author}
                  community={post.community}
                  createdAt={post.createdAt}
                  comments={post.children}
                />
              );
            })}
          </>
        )}
      </section>
      <Pagination
        path="/"
        pageNumber={searchParams?.page ? +searchParams.page : 1}
        isNext={result.isNext}
      />
    </>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

`ThreadCard.tsx` :

```
import { formatDateString } from "@/lib/utils";
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";
import DeleteThread from "../forms/DeleteThread";
import LikeButton from "../shared/LikeButton";

interface Props {
  id: string;
  loggedInUser: string;
  currentUserId: string;
  parentId: string | null;
  content: string;
  author: {
    name: string;
    image: string;
    id: string;
  };
  community: {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    image: string;
  } | null;
  createdAt: string;
  comments: {
    author: {
      image: string;
    };
  }[];
  isComment?: boolean;
}

const ThreadCard = ({
  id,
  loggedInUser,
  currentUserId,
  parentId,
  content,
  author,
  community,
  createdAt,
  comments,
  isComment,
}: Props) => {
  const commentCount = comments.length;
  const likesCount = 1;

  return (
    <article
      className={`flex w-full flex-col rounded-xl  ${
        isComment ? "px-0 xs:px-7" : "bg-dark-2 p-7"
      }`}
    >
      <div className="flex items-start justify-between">
        <div className="flex w-full flex-1 flex-row gap-4">
          <div className="flex flex-col items-center">
            <Link href={`/profile/${author.id}`} className="relative h-11 w-11">
              <Image
                src={author.image}
                alt="Profile image"
                fill
                className="cursor-pointer rounded-full"
              />
            </Link>
            <div className="thread-card_bar" />
          </div>
          <div className="flex w-full flex-col">
            <Link href={`/profile/${author.id}`} className="w-fit">
              <h4 className="cursor-pointer text-base-semibold text-light-1">
                {author.name}
              </h4>
            </Link>
            <p className="mt-2 text-small-regular text-light-2">{content}</p>
            <div className={`${isComment && "mb-10"} mt-5 flex flex-col gap-3`}>
              <div className="flex gap-3.5">
                {likesCount > 0 ? (
                  <div className="flex items-center">
                    <p className="text-subtle-medium text-gray-1">
                      {likesCount}
                    </p>
                    <div className="thread-heart-icon">
                      <LikeButton
                        threadId={id.toString()}
                        userId={currentUserId.toString()}
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                ) : (
                  <div className="thread-heart-icon">
                    <LikeButton
                      threadId={id.toString()}
                      userId={currentUserId.toString()}
                    />
                  </div>
                )}
                {commentCount > 0 ? ( // Conditional rendering of comment count
                  <Link href={`/thread/${id}`}>
                    <div className="flex items-center">
                      <p className="text-subtle-medium text-gray-1">
                        {commentCount}
                      </p>
                      <div className="thread-reply-icon">
                        <Image
                          src="/assets/reply.svg"
                          alt="comments"
                          width={24}
                          height={24}
                          className="cursor-pointer object-contain"
                        />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </Link>
                ) : (
                  <Link href={`/thread/${id}`}>
                    <div className="thread-reply-icon">
                      <Image
                        src="/assets/reply.svg"
                        alt="reply"
                        width={24}
                        height={24}
                        className="cursor-pointer object-contain"
                      />
                    </div>
                  </Link>
                )}
                <div className="thread-repost-icon">
                  <Image
                    src="/assets/repost.svg"
                    alt="repost"
                    width={24}
                    height={24}
                    className="cursor-pointer object-contain"
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="thread-share-icon">
                  <Image
                    src="/assets/share.svg"
                    alt="share"
                    width={24}
                    height={24}
                    className="cursor-pointer object-contain"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              {isComment && commentCount > 0 && (
                <Link href={`/thread/${id}`}>
                  <p className="mt-1 text-subtle-medium text-gray-1">
                    {commentCount} repl{commentCount > 1 ? "ies" : "y"}
                  </p>
                </Link>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <DeleteThread
          threadId={JSON.stringify(id)}
          loggedInUser={loggedInUser}
          authorId={author.id}
          parentId={parentId}
          isComment={isComment}
        />
      </div>
      {!isComment && commentCount > 0 && (
        <div className="ml-1 mt-3 flex items-center gap-2">
          {comments.slice(0, 2).map((comment, index) => (
            <Image
              key={index}
              src={comment.author.image}
              alt={`user_${index}`}
              width={24}
              height={24}
              className={`${index !== 0 && "-ml-5"} rounded-full object-cover`}
            />
          ))}

          <Link href={`/thread/${id}`}>
            <p className="mt-1 text-subtle-medium text-gray-1">
              {comments.length} repl{comments.length > 1 ? "ies" : "y"}
            </p>
          </Link>
        </div>
      )}
      {!isComment && community && (
        <Link
          href={`/communities/${community.id}`}
          className="mt-5 flex items-center"
        >
          <p className="text-subtle-medium text-gray-1">
            {formatDateString(createdAt)} - {community.name} Community
          </p>
          <Image
            src={community.image}
            alt={community.name}
            width={14}
            height={14}
            className="ml-1 rounded-full object-cover"
          />
        </Link>
      )}
      {!isComment && !community && (
        <Link href={`/thread/${id}`} className="mt-5 flex items-center">
          <p className="text-subtle-medium text-gray-1">
            {formatDateString(createdAt)}
          </p>
        </Link>
      )}
      {isComment && (
        <Link href={`/thread/${id}`} className="mt-5 flex items-center">
          <p className="text-subtle-medium text-gray-1">
            {formatDateString(createdAt)}
          </p>
        </Link>
      )}
    </article>
  );
};

export default ThreadCard;
```

`LikeButton.tsx` :

```
"use client";

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import useLike from "@/hooks/useLike";
import Image from "next/image";

interface Props {
  threadId: string;
  userId: string;
}

const LikeButton = ({ threadId, userId }: Props) => {
  const [isLiked, setIsLiked] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [likeFunctions, setLikeFunctions] = useState<{
    addLike: () => Promise<void>;
    removeLike: () => Promise<void>;
  } | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function setupLikeFunctions() {
      const likeFunctions = await useLike({ threadId, userId });
      setLikeFunctions(likeFunctions);
    }

    async function fetchInitialLikeStatus() {
      try {
        const response = await fetch("/api/check-like", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ threadId, userId }),
        });

        if (response.ok) {
          const data = await response.json();
          setIsLiked(data.isLiked);
        } else {
          // Handle error
        }
      } catch (error) {
        // Handle error
      }
    }

    fetchInitialLikeStatus();
    setupLikeFunctions();
  }, [threadId, userId]);

  const handleLike = async () => {
    if (isLiked) {
      await likeFunctions?.removeLike();
    } else {
      await likeFunctions?.addLike();
    }
    setIsLiked(!isLiked);
  };

  const heartImageSrc = isLiked
    ? "/assets/heart-filled.svg"
    : "/assets/heart-gray.svg";

  return (
    <Image
      src={heartImageSrc}
      alt="heart"
      width={24}
      height={24}
      className="cursor-pointer object-contain"
      onClick={handleLike}
    />
  );
};

export default LikeButton ;
```

-I tried to utilize Promise.all() in page.tsx, but the error still there

```
const userPromise = currentUser();
const userInfoPromise = userPromise.then(user => (user ? 
    fetchUser(user.id) : null));
const postsPromise = fetchPosts(
    searchParams.page ? +searchParams.page : 1,
    30
);

  const [user, userInfo, result] = await Promise.all([
    userPromise,
    userInfoPromise,
    postsPromise,
  ]);

  if (!user) return null;
  if (!userInfo?.onboarded) redirect("/onboarding");
```

I already tried to "clean" the code to where it was before the hydration error arise, but the error still there...

Comment: Have you tried to wrap your 3 awaits in page.tsx into a single promise object and then use them when all 3 have been resolved? Hydration errors are hard, but I wonder if it's the multiple awaits...

Comment: yep, the error still there...

Comment: Can you post what the hydration error says?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, this is actually quite simple, in page.tsx, for dynamic rendering based on available threads, i'm using async, wow, unbelievable, it should not used async.

so here is the fix below:

```
      <>
        {result.posts.map((post, index) => {
          return (
            <ThreadCard
              key={post._id}
              id={post._id}
              loggedInUser={user?.id || ""}
              currentUserId={userInfo._id || ""}
              parentId={post.parentId}
              content={post.text}
              author={post.author}
              community={post.community}
              createdAt={post.createdAt}
              comments={post.children}
            />
          );
        })}
      </>
```

Answer (score 1):

In case , if any of your data comes with prepared HTML from API, can also cause hydration error,

For Ex:

```
{
description:'<p>lorem ipsum<p>'
}
```

In case like above use [html-react-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser)

Also there must be any other specifications in this case, maybe you can check the console, what it says,

If nothing works, try commenting JSX code blocks, that way you'll atleast find out which section is actually causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this `heartImageSrc` check in a useEffect and push the result in a state. I'm betting that it's the SVG html that is unhandled as `isLiked` will change on re-render but everything it affects should also be in state,

```
  const heartImageSrc = isLiked
    ? "/assets/heart-filled.svg"
    : "/assets/heart-gray.svg";
```

```
const [ heartImageSrc, setHeartImageSrc ] = useState("/assets/heart-gray.svg");

useEffect(() => {
    const heartImage = isLiked ? "/assets/heart-filled.svg": "/assets/heart-gray.svg";

    setHeartImageSrc(heartImage)

}, [ isLiked ])
```

Comment: thx for ur answer, apreciate! but it's not working... but i already found the solution to my problem